# Android Intent putExtra vs Static calls?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am launching activities using an Intent as follows:

origin:

```
public class ChallongeLogin extends Activity
{
    public static String API_KEY, SUBDOMAIN;

    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        API_KEY = api_key.getText().toString();
        SUBDOMAIN = subdomain.getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChallongeEvents.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

target:

```
public class ChallongeEvents extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener 
{
    String API_KEY = ChallongeLogin.API_KEY;
    String SUBDOMAIN = ChallongeLogin.SUBDOMAIN;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_challonge_events);
    }
}
```

As you can see, all I am doing is when the `ChallongeEvents` class is created, I just take the static values from `ChallongeLogin` and put them into local variables.

Now looking at Google's official Android tutorials here:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

They do it a little differently. Instead of using static values called from the origin source, they pass the data long with `putExtra`:

```
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
```

And then they retrieve it with:

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

Why are they doing these extra steps? Is there something wrong with the way I am doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why we parse the objects as extra's on the intent is so that **you are preserving state for that instance of the intent for that specific result that is fired.**

You are setting the values of the Objects you wish to interact with, for every instance of the ChallengeLogin activity. If this challenge activity is accessed and/or modified whilst you are starting the intent for the previous interaction, you will receive the values for the current instantiation, and not the values you required to be transffered at the time of the intent initiation.

That is the just, and why static calls when starting an activity isn't the best way to do what you require.

Also, you can just go through this as well: [Using putExtra() and getExtra().](https://blograchita.wordpress.com/2012/10/24/using-putextra-and-getextras-in-android/)

Comment: Thanks... exactly the answer I was looking for. Rarely do I get an explanation so simple and cogent.